# restore objects location to default, after change to normal windows state

Tags: c#, winforms, object

I trying to restore the object(controls) location to the default(same as form load) location after I change the window state from maximize to normal.
there is simple method that I can save all the object location and after the state changes it will restore to the saved properties?

Comment: What kind of object? If you are talking about controls, they don't move unless you have set the Anchor or Dock properties. Please explain better what is the problem

Comment: I changed the controls location after I maximized the form, and when I want to normal the windowform I want to restore the controls location to the same locations like the  winload locations

Comment: Then it is your burden to save the previous location and restore it when you restore the form to the normal size.

Comment: yes, exactly, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a TableLyoutPanel and add your controls inside the cells. Set the dock property of the TableLayouPanel to Fill.No need to add any code for changing the control location.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492143.aspx
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/842418/Designing-the-Layout-of-Windows-Forms-using-a